# Suppressing password generation when creating community user with API

Tags: community, rest-api, user-record

I want to use the Salesforce API (REST or SOAP) to provision new Community Cloud Users.  I have successfully invoked the API and created the user account, however the transaction automatically generates the new user email that prompts the user to create a password.  We have integrated our Salesforce instances with our enterprise IdP and we have Single-Sign-On enabled.  We don't allow most users to login directly to Salesforce with an ID and password.

When I create a user account manually I can uncheck the "generate password immediately" box to suppress this feature.  Does anyone know if it's possible to do the same through the API?  I don't see an attribute that I can set in the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **turn off** the `Send welcome email` option from your Community. If this option is selected, Community Users whenever setup will receive the Welcome Email.

This option should be selected in cases where you want Users to login with SSO (as is your case here).

This option is available under Communities Administration --> Emails

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  We have 2 communities and I disabled it in one but I tested the user creation API in the other and forgot to turn it off.  :-)

Comment: @RussellShephard can you mark answer as accepted if it helped you solve your issue